# Cognos, report Studio : Drop down Issue

Tags: cognos

I'm using COGNOS 10.1.1. In the dropdown I have fetched 3 values from database. Let's say A1,B1 and C1. And A1 is the default value. But while running the page I see Column Name in the drop down too. How can I remove that ?

Answer (score 0):

Select value prompt and in it's properties you can set up Header Text (by default it's column name).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the Column Name - on 10.1 and prior, use JS in an HTML element. On 10.2 and up, you can use the Prompt API.